# PUT request to REST API is not working in Postman

Tags: rest

[Could be some bugs here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhFnE.png)

[In postman, nothing appears when I send a request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHVBd.png)

Comment: Try changing the postman response body view from pretty json to raw text.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.